# Best_in_place collection 1 to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, best-in-place

I'm trying to be able to controle my usermanagement directly over the index page with best_in_place. But when it comes to selecting the role it doesnt work for me till now.

My models look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
  before_create :set_default_role

   def set_default_role
    self.role ||= Role.find_by_name('Guest')
  end


end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    has_and_belongs_to_many :permissions
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :permissions
end
```

What I did until now is trying to select the foreign key `role_id` over collection select but I cant get it working that I see the names of existing roles in my select dropdown.

```
<td><%= best_in_place user, :role_id, :type => :select, :collection => "???" %></td>
```

Hope someone can help.

Best regards!

Edit: **user_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def update
    @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    respond_with @user
  end

private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:role_id)
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: You can see it above now!

Comment: Try this `<%= best_in_place user, :role_id, :type => :select, :collection => @users.map { |i| [i.id, i.name] } %>`

Comment: Hey, your code is nearly perfect. Just had to replace @users.map with Role.all.map cause I want to select the roles. But now it works fine. Add it as answer and I will rate it. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm,yes you were right.I will be adding it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, one more small question: If I change a users role now it doesnt update the table right away. I have to refresh the page to make is visible. How can I change that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you

```
<%= best_in_place user, :role_id, :type => :select, :collection => Role.all.map { |i| [i.id, i.name] } %>
```

More info **[here](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place)**